# Problem binding to default Membership.Provider in App_Start

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I'm trying to use Ninject to provide my custom MembershipProvider with an instance of the (default) AspNetSqlMembershipProvider:

```
Bind<IMembershipService>()
  .To<MembershipService>()
  .WithConstructorArgument("provider", System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider));
```

I'm instantiating my Ninject module using the standard MVC3 pattern in the App_Start, specifically I am invoking the static Start() method using the WebActivator

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyProject.App_Start.NinjectMVC3), "Start")]

public static void Start()
{
    DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestModule));
    bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
}
```

The problem I have is that at this point, the default System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider as not been established and the application errors on start-up.

To get over this problem, I have restructured the code by adding a WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyProject.App_Start.NinjectMVC3), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyProject.App_Start.NinjectMVC3), "PostStart")]

public static void Start()
{
    DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestModule));
}
```

and moving the bootstrapperInitialze() call into a PostStart() method:

```
public static void PostStart()
{
    bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
}
```

This resolves the problem, but I was wondering if a) this is likely to introduce other problems, or b) if there was an alternative approach?

ADDITIONAL DETAILS:
I have tried modifying the bindings as suggested, but I get the following compilation error:

'Ninject.Syntax.BindingRoot.Bind()' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

For information, here is the listing for my MembershipModule:

```
public class MembershipModule : NinjectModule
{
  public override void Load()
  {
     // Membership Service
     Bind<Abl.Mvc.Models.Membership.Abstract.IMembershipService>()
       .To<Abl.Mvc.Models.Membership.Services.MembershipService>()
       .WithConstructorArgument("provider", System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider)
       .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", MembershipProvider.GetConnectionString());

     // This line errors
     Bind<MembershipProvider>.ToMethod(ctx => System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider);
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your bindings to:

```
Bind<IMembershipService>().To<MembershipService>();
Bind<MembershipProvider>().ToMethod(ctx => Membership.Provider);
```

Comment: Thanks Remo, I have tried your suggestion, but get a compilation error - please see updated question for details.

Comment: @Neilski Unfortunately the Stackoverflow editor has no C# syntax checking. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you Remo - this worked perfectly - and tidied up my code at the same time!  I now need to understand the 'how' and 'why' this works and will spend some long overdue time with the Ninject Wiki to try and figure this 'magic' out.  Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

[assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof((MyProject.App_Start.NinjectMVC3), "OnApplicationStarted")]

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Application started.
    /// </summary>
    public static void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        // Do your bindings here.
    }
```

Do your bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel) in Start... not post start.